# ¿Cómo funciona "onAuthStateChanged"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-auth

En la documentación de firebase me indica esto:

> **onAuthStateChanged**
>
> `onAuthStateChanged ( nextOrObserver :  Observer < any > | ( ( a :  User | null ) => any ) ,  error ? :  ( a :  Error ) => any ,  completed ? :  firebase.Unsubscribe ) : firebase.Unsubscribe`
>
> Adds an observer for changes to the user's sign-in state.
>
> Prior to 4.0.0, this triggered the observer when users were signed in,
> signed out, or when the user's ID token changed in situations such as
> token expiry or password change. After 4.0.0, the observer is only
> triggered on sign-in or sign-out.
>
> Parameters
>
> nextOrObserver: Observer | ((a: User | null) => any)
>
> Optional error: (a: Error) => any (a: Error): any Parameters a: Error
> Returns any
>
> Optional completed: firebase.Unsubscribe Returns
> firebase.Unsubscribe
>
> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in.
>   }
> });
> ```

Según esto me dice que que retorna un "unsubscribe"...es como si el retorno fuese la cancelación de una subscripción?

Lo que se le pasa como parámetro "user", es un observador?... no lo entiendo muy bien.Si "user" es un observador, aqué observable se ha subscrito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, el parámetro es un observador y retorna una función que puedes usar para cancelar la suscripción. El uso es algo así

```
const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  }
});

// cuando quieras remover el observer
unsubscribe()
```

El observable al que se suscribe representa el estado del usuario autenticado. El valor de `user` es un objeto [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) que contiene los datos del usuario que ha iniciado sesión o `null` si nadie está conectado. Este observer se ejecuta cada vez que alguien inicia o cierra sesión.

Si te interesa saber más sobre esta función puedes leer [este post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0).

**EDIT** Respuestas a los comentarios:

A) No ves al `Observable` ni dónde se hace la suscripción porque eso lo hace internamente la librería.

B) `user` no es el observer, es sólo el parámetro de la función que se convertirá el método `next` del observer. El `Observer` en sí mismo lo crea internamente la librería con las funciones que le pasas como parámetro a `onAuthStateChanged`. Como lo dice su descripción, el primer parámetro que recibe se convertirá en el método `next`, el segundo en `error` y el tercero en `complete`. Aunque los parámetros 2 y 3 son opcionales.

Si aún tienes dudas deberías mirar el código fuente. No puedo explicarte todo pero en resumen la suscripción se hace en el método [registerStateListener](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/5ad7ff2ae955c297556223e6cb3ad9d4b897f664/packages-exp/auth-exp/src/core/auth/auth_impl.ts#L496) que es llamado directamente por [onAuthStateChanged](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/5ad7ff2ae955c297556223e6cb3ad9d4b897f664/packages-exp/auth-exp/src/core/auth/auth_impl.ts#L362). El `Observable` como tal se crea [aquí](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/5ad7ff2ae955c297556223e6cb3ad9d4b897f664/packages/rxfire/auth/index.ts#L32).

Comment: Ok, gracias por la info. Ok, ahora entiendo que lo que devuelve es la cancelación del observable. pero tengo dos dudas:

Comment: A) en ese código que me has pasado no veo el "observable" en si por ninguna parte, ni en qué momento se crea ese observable y no sé en qué momento se ha hecho la subscripción del observador (que en este caso el observador se supone que es "user") al observable.

Comment: B) si "user" es un Obervador que subscribimos a un obervable, se supone que puedo configurarles los métodos "next", "error" y "complete"?

Comment: @casiopea2000 cuál es la razón para no aceptar la respuesta?

Comment: No sé muy bien cómo va eso de aceptar respuesta. Yo votaba positivo pensando que así te premiaba de alguna manera. Cuándo se usa "aceptar respuesta"?

Comment: Disculpa, creí que conocías el funcionamiento del sitio. Aceptar una respuesta indica que tu problema o duda fue resulto. Si no aceptas ninguna significa que sigues esperando respuestas. Veo que tienes muchas preguntas abiertas y seguramente ya solucionaste muchas de ellas. Deberías aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron o en su defecto escribir y aceptar tu propia respuesta. De esta manera puedes ayudar personas que tengan el mismo problema. También te puede interesar leer [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ok, gracias por la info!